# Using iptables to make mySQL listen on two ports

Tags: iptables

I've got a mySQL machine I need to establish a remote connection to. The problem is that the outbound connection machine is on a network which blocks port 3306 outgoing, and the mySQL process is shared with other applications/developers.

My current thinking is to use iptables wizardry to get it to change ports as its listening on them. I've found

I've found iptables commands which work on a NAT-based level e.g.

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp --dport 8080 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3306
```

I'm having a hard time finding an appropriate iptables target which works on INPUT

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this on the INPUT chain (filter table)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ummm... You already have the answer there :-)

If thats not working, maybe you are blocking those ports on the INPUT chain. You need to add accept rules for those as well (both 8080 and 3306 I think).  The PREROUTING chain is before the INPUT chain.